# how to assign the coordinates read from MousePosition class into variable

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, openlayers

in the posted code below, i get the coordinates based on where the mouse pointer is moving on the map. in other words, as the mouse moves on the map the code below gets the longitude and latitude based on where the mouse pointer
is.

the coordinates are displayed in 'mouse-position' as mentioned below for example 6.6920092, 51.1328600, longitude and latitude respectively

```
                target: document.getElementById('mouse-position')
```

how can i split the values of the read coodinates so that i can save the longitude in a variable and the latitude in aother variable
the problem is the coordinates are provided in the

```
 new MousePosition({...})
```

how can i have them in a variable

is there any listeners with event mouse over or hover i can subscribe to??

**code**:

```
var mousePositionControl = new MousePosition({
            className: 'custom-mouse-position',
            coordinateFormat: createStringXY(7),
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
            // be placed within the map.
            target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
            undefinedHTML: '',//for what to be rendered when the mouse leaves map scope: values https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_control_MousePosition-MousePosition.html
          });
        this.map = new Map({  
            controls: defaultControls().extend([mousePositionControl]),            
            target: 'map',
            layers: [],
            view: new View({
                center: [properties.centerX, properties.centerY],
                zoom: properties.zoom
            })

        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `pointermove` event without needing a MousePosition control

```
var lonlat;
map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
  lonlat = toLonLat(e.coordinate);
});
```

Comment: I have not tried it yet and I will acknowledge when done. However I have a question please, how did you know that there exist such function the one called pointer move?

Comment: It is used on some of the examples, such as https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-hover-features.html